# HTTP to HTTPS redirect even for IP

Tags: apache-2.4, http, redirect, https, rewrite

I have already read  many question on basic http -> https redirection, but it all talks about the redirect/rewrite including only domain name.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
Redirect / https://www.example.com/
```

For eg this above snippet will redirect all request to http:www.example.com to  https:www.example.com 
This ofcourse is the [apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect) recommended way.

But how would we redirect http to https even if request is based on IP. 
Like http:ip to https:ip How can this be achieved? 
I know that https is for domain name, but I have this particular requirement of client being able to access over IP as well.

Answer (score 2):

Requests using the ip-address (or HTTP 1.0 requests without a `Host:` header) and those for unknown domains are handled by the [`default VirtualHost`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html#default) which defaults to the **first** `VirtualHost` entry unless explicitly defined with:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:*>
    Redirect / https://www.example.com/
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

So depending on your current configuration:

- you may not need to do anything to handle requests using the ip-address (i.e. when you only have a single VirtualHost or the www.example.com is already the first entry)
- or you can re-order the current VirtualHost entries so that www.example.com becomes the first VirtualHost entry
- explicitly define the `_default_:80` VirtualHost

Answer (score 0):

Simply write in the end of `http.conf` file.

```
##this is for http redirection to domain name###
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias *
Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

##This is for https redirection to domain name###
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias *
Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have only one IP address, you may use something like this (NOT TESTED):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias *
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R]
```